# How to store OCR1A value in ATmega16

Tags: pwm, avr-gcc

I am working on a robotics project. Using timers in ATmega16, I am controlling servo motors.
By incrementing the value of OCR1A I am manipulating the servo motor. After getting the desired position of servo, I want to store the value of OCR1A for that position so that I can use it afterwards to get the same position.

OCR1A is a 16 bit register. How can I store this value? Will variables do the job?

Comment: You mean store to be preserved after a power down or just store in a RAM position?

Comment: Not on power down. Just want to store that 16 bit value in RAM.

Comment: You can use a 16 bit unsigned variable, like unsigned int

Comment: Can you tell me how to declare it?

Comment: Thank you.Is it possible to store it even after power down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <avr/io.h>

// declaration of a global variable
unsigned int my_global_16bit_variable;

int main(void)
{
    // declaration of a local variable
    unsigned int my_local_16bit_variable = 0;

    my_local_16bit_variable = OCR1A;   // assign value to the local variable
    my_global_16bit_variable = OCR1A;   // assign value to the global variable

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

The local variable is only valid inside main, the global variable can be accessed form anywhere.

If you intend to use the variable is shared between a function and an interrupt then it should be declared as global volatile.

```
#include <avr/io.h>

// declaration of a global variable
volatile unsigned int my_global_16bit_variable;
.....
```

---

To store a variable in the internal AVR eeprom

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/eeprom.h>

// macro for easier usage
#define read_eeprom_word(address) eeprom_read_word ((const uint16_t*)address)
#define write_eeprom_word(address,value) eeprom_write_word ((uint16_t*)address,(uint16_t)value)

//declare an eeprom variable
unsigned int EEMEM   my_eeprom_word;

int main(void)
{

write_eeprom_word(&my_eeprom_word,OCR1A);       // store value in eeprom

OCR1A = read_eeprom_word(&my_eeprom_word);     // restore from eeprom

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

---

The variable length are shown in [stdint.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html)

Integer types having exactly the specified width

```
typedef signed char     int8_t
typedef unsigned char   uint8_t
typedef signed int  int16_t
typedef unsigned int    uint16_t
typedef signed long int     int32_t
typedef unsigned long int   uint32_t
typedef signed long long int    int64_t
typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t
```

You can either use `unsigned int` or `unt16_t` , I prefer the uintxx_t format

Comment: Is unsigned int capable of 16 bits?

Comment: @user3052614 Yes it can, please refer to the updated answer

Comment: Should I store it in EEPROM if I want to use the value even after power down?

Comment: @user3052614 You can but storing in eeprom takes slightly longer time (in case it matters) and has a limit of about 100000 writes (if I remember the number correctly). If you intend to write it several times per minute it's a good idea to use RAM.

Comment: I want to store an array of values in EEPROM. Can you tell me how to store an array in EPROM?